# Select rows with common values of n columns from multiple data frames in R

Tags: r

I have two dataframes `A` and `B` and each has two columns `first` and `second` (or in general `n` columns and `M` dataframes). I would like to get these rows from `A` and `B` where columns `first` and `second` takes combination of values that exists in both dataframes.

Example:

`A:`

```
    first   second  3rd 4th ...
1   X       1       1   1
2   X       1       2   3   ...
3   X       2       5   6   ...
4   Y       2       5   6   ...
5   Y       3       NA  NA  ...
```

`B:`

```
    first   second  3rd 4th ...
1   X       1       0   1
2   X       3       4   1   ...
3   X       2       1   0   ...
4   Y       2       0   1   ...
5   Y       44      5   5   ...
```

We have the following common combination `P` of `A` and `B`:

```
    first   second 
1   X       1      
2   X       2       
3   Y       2
```

**The final selected rows should be then like that:**

`A_selected:`

```
    first   second  3rd 4th ...
1   X       1       1   1
2   X       1       2   3   ...
3   X       2       5   6   ...
4   Y       2       5   6   ...
```

`B_selected:`

```
    first   second  3rd 4th ...
1   X       1       0   1
3   X       2       1   0   ...
4   Y       2       0   1   ...
```

What I did initially was an inner join using `dplyr` package:

```
target_columns <- c('first', 'second');
common_columns <- dplyr::inner_join(A[target_columns], B[target_columns])
```

But I do not know how to take it further, that is how to select rows based on `common_columns` dataframe.

I would appreciate your help

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
A_selected <- semi_join(A, B, by = target_columns)
B_selected <- semi_join(B, A, by = target_columns)
```

For many dataframes

```
intersect_range <- purrr::reduce(list(A, B, C, D, E), inner_join, by = target_columns)
selected <- lapply(list(A, B, C, D, E), semi_join, intersect_range, by = target_columns)
```

Comment: This is great! Although is it applicable with many dataframes? It solves my problem now but I think it would be great to have a general solution. Nevertheless kudos for this!

Comment: Works great, I guess it could be improved by not doing inner_joins on entire dataframes? But that's a matter of taste

Comment: Agreed. It is more efficient to only `inner_join` columns that are needed, especially when  dataframes are large. However, I think I will leave my answer like this for simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

a `data.table` approach

**sample data**

```
library( data.table )
A <- data.table::fread("first   second  3rd 4th
   X       1       1   1
   X       1       2   3   
   X       2       5   6   
   Y       2       5   6   
   Y       3       NA  NA")  

B <- fread("    first   second  3rd 4th 
   X       1       0   1
   X       3       4   1   
   X       2       1   0   
   Y       2       0   1   
   Y       44      5   5")
```

**code**

```
#columns to find common values in
colnames <- c( "first", "second" )
#put in a list, 
L <- list(A,B)
#only keep first ans second colum
L.subset <- lapply(L, function(x) setDT(x)[, .SD, .SDcols = colnames ] )
#common values
common_values <- Reduce( intersect, L.subset )
#    first second
# 1:     X      1
# 2:     X      2
# 3:     Y      2

#final
lapply( L, function(x) setDT(x)[ first %in% common_values$first & second %in% common_values$second, ] )

# [[1]]
#    first second 3rd 4th
# 1:     X      1   1   1
# 2:     X      1   2   3
# 3:     X      2   5   6
# 4:     Y      2   5   6
# 
# [[2]]
#    first second 3rd 4th
# 1:     X      1   0   1
# 2:     X      2   1   0
# 3:     Y      2   0   1
```

Comment: It might be less elegant than the other answer but it's certainly more general and I appreciate it. I will test it more thoroughly and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: It's great although does not work for many (more than 2 ) datasets (Reduce step). Im not sure why